# X-Cart 5 Adding Preferred Delivery Date to Checkout

Tags: date, field, checkout, x-cart

This is my first time working on the X-Cart 5 and I am struggling to add a new field to the **Checkout** page that will store a **preferred delivery date** entered by customer. The value of the field will be passed into the form and saved in the database. Afterwards, I can access that value and show it on the invoice page as well as the Order list page from the Admin panel.

What I have done so far: 
I am working using **CustomSkin** module. 
I have defined a new **$preferredDeliveryDate** property in **..CustomSkin../Model/Order**. 
Inside the **View/Checkout** class I have found there are two steps: **Shipping and Review**. Instead of defining a new step, I was hoping to reuse the functionality of **Customer notes** field right before the place order button as it was simply added as HTML. However, I am not clear how data of the field is passed (JS?) and how to access it later. I need to be able to update the **$preferredDeliveryDate** after the Place order and access it to show it's value.

If it is possible would you show where and how to add this field as well as how to access it and print on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should look into these:

- `skins/default/en/checkout/steps/review/parts/place_order.note.tpl` -
  displays the field during checkout
- `\XLite\Controller\Customer\Checkout::doPayment()` - stores the field
  value in the order

So, you are to add your field to the checkout and "decorate" the `doPayment()` method from your custom module so that it stores the field value in the order too. Also, you may need to decorate the `\XLite\Model\Order` class to add the new column to the orders database table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Would you please be more specific as I have no previous xcart experience. I would appreciate if you could also provide some code samples.